# class-transformer does not work : Transform function is not called

Tags: node.js, typescript, typegraphql, class-transformer

I try to use class-transformer but i can't do it.
I also use type-graphql and @typegoose/typegoose
Here's my code:

***My Decorator***

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export function Trim() {
  console.log('DECORATOR');

  return Transform(({ value }: { value: string }) => {
    console.log('value: ', value);
    return value.trim();
  });
}
```

***My InputType***

```
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator';
import { InputType, Field } from 'type-graphql';
import { User } from '../Entities/User';
import { Trim } from '../../Decorators/Sanitize';

@InputType({ description: 'Input for user creation' })
export class AddUserInput implements Partial<User> {
  @Field()
  @Trim()
  @IsEmail({ domain_specific_validation: true, allow_utf8_local_part: false })
  email!: string;
}
```

***My Resolver***

```
import { Arg, Mutation, Resolver } from 'type-graphql';
import { User } from '../Entities/User';
import { AddUserInput } from '../Types/UsersInputs';

@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolvers {
  @Mutation(() => String, { description: 'Register an admin' })
  async createAccount(@Arg('data') data: AddUserInput): Promise<string> {
    console.log({ ...data });
    return data.email;
  }
}
```

***My Entity***

```
import { prop, getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { ObjectType, Field } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType({ description: 'User model' })
export class User {
  @Field({ description: 'The user email' })
  @prop({ required: true, unique: true, match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'] })
  email!: string;
}

export const UserModel = getModelForClass(User, {
  schemaOptions: { timestamps: true }
});
```

***My Request***

```
POST http://localhost:5000/app HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-REQUEST-TYPE: GraphQL

mutation 
{
   createAccount (data : {
       email: "   email@gmail.com    ",
   })
}
```

The problem is that the `console.log('value: ', value)` inside Transform function is never call and my email is not trim.

Also `console.log('DECORATOR')` is not call when I do the request but just one time when server starting.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Typegoose transpiles classes into mongoose schemas & models, it does not apply any validation / transformation aside from mongoose provided ones, so your `class-transformer` decorators would only be called when using the class directly and using its functions. (like `plainToClass` and `classToPlain`)

In your case, it would be better to either use [PropOptions `get & set`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#get--set) or [pre-hooks](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/hooks#pre).

As a note, typegoose provides a guide for using class-transformer with typegoose classes [Integration Example: class-transformer](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/integration-examples/using-with-class-transformer), just to show that it can be used like normal classes.

Also note, it is currently recommended against using `class-transformer` because of mentioned issues inside the documentation.

Comment: Hello hasezoey, thank you very much for your answer but I'm trying to sanitize the email property of an input type, I think the problem is more related to type-graphql than typegoose.